# How does an over-release or over-retain occur?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release, retain

Not sure wether or not this question is too broad, in the case where it is can you explain in a more general preceptive and maybe give some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your tags, I'm going to answer specifically for ARC.

Objects are generally *over-retained* when parts of the code create **strong** references to them inappropriately.

For example, a common way for an *over-retain* to occur is if two objects have strong references to each other. Strong references prevent an object from being deallocated - in the case where two objects reference each other in this way then a cycle is created, meaning that neither can be deallocated until the other one has been.

Another example is when using blocks as variables. Say an object has an instance block variable/property that includes something like:

```
self.blockProperty = ^{
    self.property = value;
};
```

This creates a strong reference within the block to the object itself. The correct thing here is to create a weak reference to `self` and use this within the block, but the subtlety of this is frequently easy to overlook.

On the other hand, objects are generally *over-released* when the opposite occurs, that is when the code has a weak reference to an object that, in reality, it relies upon. This may mean that the object is deallocated when it is still required. Alternatively, the object may have been inadvertently set to `nil` or perhaps it was never initiated in the first place.

Both of these problems are (in my experience) much less common when using ARC, but that doesn't mean that you can forget about them. Good usage of profiling tools is helpful for picking the former up, and you'll usually know when the latter is a problem because you'll be seeing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or similar, which is always fun to debug. This won't always be the case, however, as weak references get set to `nil` when their target is deallocated, and as such you may not pick up the error when you attempt to send messages to them.

Comment: Don't confuse overretain with retain cycles.

Comment: Well, in the context of ARC, that's essentially what it does mean. As in, an object is over-retained. But I agree, this means something very different for MRC

Answer (score 1):

*Overrelease* happens when an object receives more `release` messages than `retain` messages, that is, it is already deallocated when the last `release` message is sent to it. The result is typically a crash or undefined behavior.

*Overretain* means there was a `retain` in your code that was never paired with a `release` (forgotten `release` somewhere), the object was never deallocated. Autorelease pools and `autorelease` message was created to prevent *overretain*. The result is usually too much memory needed by the application but the user won't probably notice if the error is not repeated many times.

Of course, this can happen only under Manual Reference Counting (MRC) because under Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) you never send `retain` or `release` manually.

There are some specific cases when object use manual reference counting (e.g. Core Foundation objects) and you have to use `__bridge` casts to use them under ARC. If you use the bridging casts incorrectly, similar problem can arise. I am not sure this falls under the name `overrelease` or `overretain` though.

By the way, don't confuse overretain with retain cycles. That's a different error and has different solutions under MRC and ARC.

Answer (score -1):

Under ARC environment, over-release and over-retain happened only with `__bridge_transfer` and `__bridge_retained` casts (Core Foundation provides the same functionality with `CFBridgingRelease` and `CFBridgingRetain`).

Over-release:

```
NSObject *obj = (__bridge_transfer NSObject*)(__bridge void*)[[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Over-retain:

```
NSObject* obj = (__bridge NSObject*)(__bridge_retained void*)[[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Comment: It would be great if that were the case, but (as of Xcode 8.0) it's not.  I can still get overrelease errors in pure Swift, without any bridging.  It's possible these are the result of compiler bugs, but that just emphasizes that developers still need to understand the memory model, and can't trust the compiler to always save them!